# How to set PR_SECURITY_FLAGS MAPI properties from EWS or Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

How to set emails PR_SECURITY_FLAGS (http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003) property with any of the below values. with EWS or Graph API

NONE | 0x0000 | Message has no security ENCRYPTED | 0x0001 | Message is encrypted SIGNED | 0x0002 | Message is signed SIGNED | ENCRYPTED | 0x0003 | Message is signed and encrypted

I am working on Outlook latest web add-in (Office.Js + Manifest) for encrypting emails,  Please help me here

Answer (score 1):

That property is not real - it is never actually stored on the item. It is just a way to let the Outlook Object Model know (through `PropertyAccessor.SetProperty`) that the item needs to be signed/encrypted when it is sent.

There is no EWS or Graph equivalent to the best of my knowledge.